# How to display html table with months as headers and missing data

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I need to make a table displaying evaluation scores for different sites but not every site will have data for each month. How can I get the data into the right month column and then display blank cells where there is no data?

This is a sample array:

```
Array
(
[Site 1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 89
        [3] => 84
        [4] => 96
        [6] => 91
        [8] => 90
        [12] => 99
    )

[Site 2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 90
        [3] => 93
        [4] => 88
    )

[Site 3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 92
        [3] => 92
        [4] => 89
        [6] => 94
        [8] => 86
    )

[Site 4] => Array
    (
        [1] => 93
        [2] => 88
        [3] => 92
        [4] => 89
        [5] => 93
        [6] => 94
        [8] => 90
        [12] => 91
    )

)
```

And this is as far as I got with the php. I know there is problem with the for loop but I can't figure what to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Sites</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th>";  

foreach($report as $site=>$array)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$site</td>";

    foreach($array as $month=>$score)
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
        {
            if($month==$i)
            {
                echo "<td>$score</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }           
    }       
    echo "</tr>";
}   

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: From just eyeballing the code, the logic seems okay. What is going wrong with it?

Comment: The for loop creates a huge number of empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if a month exists for each `$i`. What you're doing is checking if **each** `$i` is equal to **each** month, which is, of course, almost always false and produces huge number of empty cells. Just see how many cells in total you produce (per row): number of months for won site multiplied by 12.

Here is a proper way to do it:

```
echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Sites</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th>";

foreach($report as $site=>$array)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$site</td>";

    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        if (isset($array[$i]))
        {
            echo "<td>".$array[$i]."</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

or, shorter,

```
echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Sites</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th><th>Mar</th><th>Apr</th><th>May</th><th>Jun</th><th>Jul</th><th>Aug</th><th>Sep</th><th>Oct</th><th>Nov</th><th>Dec</th>";

foreach($report as $site=>$array)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$site</td>";

    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
    {
        echo "<td>".(isset($array[$i]) ? $array[$i] : '&nbsp;')."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is simple, easy to understand and, most importantly, it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop validate that the key exist with issset or array_key_exists

```
foreach($array as $score){

    for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){

        if(array_key_exists($i,$score)){
            echo '<td>'.$scode[$i].'<td>';
        }else{
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't work. Got this warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array